# Please explain one line of perl code

Tags: perl, sed

I have such line from https://camlistore.googlesource.com/camlistore/+/master/third_party/rewrite-imports.sh

```
find . -type f -name '*.go' -exec perl -pi -e 's!"code.google.com/!"camlistore.org/third_party/code.google.com/!' {} \;
```

I would like help understanding what exactly this does:

```
perl -pi -e 's!"code.google.com/!"camlistore.org/third_party/code.google.com/!'
```

Especialy exclamation marks and `"`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

- `-p` means "run the expression for each line, and print the result"
- `-i` means "edit the input file in place"
- `-e` means "the next parameter is the Perl expression to evaluate"

For the expression itself:

- The `!` marks are the separators for the `s` (substitution) operator. *Any* non-alphanumeric character can be used for that - whatever follows the `s`.
- The `"` characters don't mean anything special, they're just part of the text to be replaced, and the replacement.

So we have:

- `s`: substitute
- `!`: (separator)
- `"code.google.com/`: text to find
- `!`: (separator)
- `"camlistore.org/third_party/code.google.com/`: replacement text
- `!`: (separator)

Which all means:

- For each line in the file
- Find the text `"code.google.com/`
- And (if found) replace it with `"camlistore.org/third_party/code.google.com/`

Answer (score 1):

The bangs `!` are just an alternative delimiter for the search and replace regex [`s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html).

Because the content of the search and replace includes forward slashes, it makes sense to use a different delimiter to avoid having to escape them all.  Exclamation points are sometimes used for this purpose `s!!!`, but my preferred alternate are braces:  `s{}{}`.

As for what that code is done, it's replacing all references to `"code.google.com/` with `"camlistore.org/third_party/code.google.com/` in the found files.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty straightforward search-and-replace. The `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` operator sees if a string matches the regular expression pattern and replaces the part that matches with the value of the replacement string.

Since sometimes `/` characters are an inconvenient delimiter (such as dealing with web URIs), Perl allows you to swap them out for other characters, in this case they chose to use `!`.

The `-p` switch causes Perl to assume a loop around the code in question for processing lines. The `-i` switch allows input lines to be edited in-place as they are processed, optionally preserving the original in another file. (See [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for the gory details.)

So all this code is doing is replacing lines that contain `"code.google.com/` with `"camlistore.org/third_party/code.google.com/`.